# Duplicate a Word table using Applescript

Tags: ms-word, applescript, osx-snow-leopard

I have AS working to write data into a table in Word 2011 and I can get the properties of that table, but how can I duplicate the table and add a new table to the active document but with a different name/ID? abFile is specified before the tell block.

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
activate
open abFile
set tableProps to get properties of tables of active document
end tell
```

What I'd like is a way to say:

```
make new table in active document with tableProps and name "2"
```

Comment: As far as I can tell from the dictionary, there is no "name" property for MS Words tables.  At least not for Word 2011 on OSX 10.8.5.  Also I think for any properly implemented applescript dictionary, object ids are **always** assigned by the applescript runtime environment, and are read-only to the script

Comment: Looking at the Word 2011 dictionary in SL I'd agree but how can I make a new table with the same properties then and let AS look after the ID?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I tried was this:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open abFile
    set tableList to tables of active document
    set firstTable to item 1 of tableList
    make new table in active document with properties (properties of firstTable)
end tell
```

This does create a new table, but none of the properties appear to actually be copied - at least numbers of rows and columns are different.

Another thing you can try is simply to duplicate a table:

```
tell application "Microsoft Word"
    activate
    open abFile
    set tableList to tables of active document
    set firstTable to item 1 of tableList
    duplicate item 1 of tableList
end tell
```

Again this does create a new table, but it's cell contents are the same as the original table.  I'm not sure if you just want properties to be copied or if you want the cell contents to be copied as well.